# Java Generics: wildcards again

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a container that would accept specific classes only. Using generics as follows:

```
    static class Test1<C extends Test1> {
            C field = null;
            public C getField() {
                return field;
            }
            public void setField(C field) {
                this.field = field;
            }
        }
        static class Test2 extends Test1{
        }

class MainTest {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                List<Test1<? extends Test1>> list = new ArrayList<Test1<? extends Test1>>();
                Test1<Test2> newInstance = new Test1<Test2>();
                list.add(newInstance);
                Test1<Test2> value = list.get(1);
    }
}
```

Just want to understand why this List> would accept a newInstance object, but compilation time error occurs while I'm fetching "Test1 value" back?
Is there any chance to workaround the problem?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE
Many noticed that " `Test1<? extends Test1>`, where ? MAY NOT be equal to Test2."
I totally agree but as far as I understand in this case I need to type cast the extracted value to `Test1<Test2>` and that means that the whole point of generics is lost in this case... Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why don't you declare the list as `List<Test1<Test2>> list`?

Comment: `Test1<Test2>` is an instance of `Test1<? extends Test1<?>>`, but `Test1<? extends Test1<?>>` is not an instance of `Test1<Test2>`. (You also have rare types there - a mix of generic and raw types - which is bad news.)

Comment: I want list to contain all combinations of Test1 containing any of its descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you `list.get(1)` returns `Test1<? extends Test1>`, where `?` MAY NOT be equal to `Test2`.

On the onther hand `list.add(...)` accepts `Test1<? extends Test1>`, i.e. Test1 with ANY generics parameter which is inheritor of Test1.

Comment: So you're saying that typecasting is the only way to workaround? But in this case the whole point of using generics is lost...

Comment: The point of Generics is to ensure type safety at design time, correct me if I am wrong. And if it so, then type casting is basically ruins the whole idea. Would be glad to hear your considerations.

Comment: You don't need to cast anything here. If you want `list.get()` and `list.add()` work "as you expected" merely make `List<Test1<Test2>>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can store a Test1<> with every object that is a child of Test1 as a typed parameter. Let's say you have
class Test3 extends Test1
then you would have

```
Test1<Test2> value = list.get(1);
```

but how the list would be sure that the element with index 1 has a generic type Test2 but not Test3 as it accepts every subtype of Test1 ().

The proper way to fetch the element is using

```
Test1<? extends Test1> test1 = list.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the problem by writing

```
Test1<? extends Test1> value = list.get(1);
```

instead of

```
Test1<Test2> value = list.get(1);
```

or by making a cast to Test1.

Comment: And after that should I typecaset to Test1<Test2>?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Test1<? extends Test1>> list = new ArrayList<Test1<? extends Test1>>();
```

this is a read only list, you can only insert null to this list, nothing else

instead use below:

```
List<Test1<? extends Test1>> list = new ArrayList<Test1<XXX>>();  where XXX extends Test1
```